# "How to fix the 'csrf' error in 'Django'?"

Tags: django, atom-editor

I'm using Django with Atom engine and when I log in to the link http://127.0.0.1:8000 it gets me a csrf error. what should I do?

Comment: in the .html file if you have some form tag like <form> </form>
you must input {%csrf_token%}  for the cross atack its like defence :) Welcome to our community by the way :)

Comment: please read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197321/csrf-error-in-django Also paste your html

Answer (score 0):

```
 For example this is my file form


 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% if makale.makale_foto %}
          <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ makale.makale_foto.url }}" alt="">
              {% else %}
              <div class="alert alert-danger">Fotoğraf Eklenmemiş</div>
          {% endif %}
          {% csrf_token %} //this is csrf 
           {{ form|crispy }}
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="width:100%" value="Kaydet">
      </form>
```

Comment: but there are many pages like views, model, URLs. In which page should I add it?

Comment: İn templates directory on html file under the <form> tag

Answer (score 0):

What you mean "There are many pages like views, model, URLs" ? You have wrong understanding about components (IMHO).

You should send **csrftoken** to server, every time you make **HTTP POST** request.
Imagine that you have a form,,,

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="surname" />
    {% csrf_token %}  <!-- This template tag generates html "hidden" field with csrf token -->
    <input type="submit" value="click" />
</form>
```

If you are making **Ajax Request**, you must also send csrftoken on the server, there are many strategies of it. The most important is that **Django** has **CsrfMiddleware** which reads data from **request.POST** and **request.COOKIES** and compares each other. It's also possible avoid **csrf** protection. Read documentation carefully.

Comment: I am absolutely clueless. Do you mind showing me a picture of that?

Comment: No, you should provide us more information about you html form, or ajax calls.